# UITableView performance issue after calling reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uitableview

I'm an Android developer working on my first iOS project. I have a UITableView that displays almost 37,500 rows. One row for each item in an grocery store. The list has 3 columns one containing the item name and the other 2 containing other important data. The columns are sortable, and to handle the sorting I sort the data array as I need to and call `[tableView reloadData]` after I'm done sorting the array. This works fine except there is a long delay of at least a few seconds after reloading the data where the main thread is locked up doing work. I'm no stranger to list performance as I've had to make smooth lists numerous times in Android. So from what I can tell I'm not really doing much to cause this. The only thing I can think of is just the large number of items in my array. Here is the relevant code:

**Here are the table methods I am overriding:**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return [self.data count];
 }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
ReplenishListCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ReplenishListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

NSMutableDictionary *dictData = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.nameLabel.text = dictData[@"item-description"];
cell.firstLicationColumnLabel.text = dictData[@"store-count"];
cell.secondLicationColumnLabel.text = dictData[@"other-count"];

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)replenishTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[self showActivityIndicator];

ReplenishListCell *cell = (ReplenishListCell*) [replenishTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *nameClicked = cell.nameLabel.text;

[database getItemByName:nameClicked :self];
}
```

**Here is the method I use to sort the array:**

```
-(void) sortArray:(NSString *) dictionaryKey {
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:dictionaryKey ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName];
NSArray *sortedArray = [data sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

[data removeAllObjects];
[data addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I do not have any performance issues until after calling `[self.tableView reloadData]`. So I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing, or is there maybe a better way of reloading the data besides `reloadData`? Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've spent a few hours now debugging and Googling and I haven't come up with a solution yet.

Comment: Is the order of your array important?

Comment: You should first profile your code with Instruments and locate the actual culprit. Then, and only then, you can make an informed decision how to approach the issue.

Comment: The array can be sorted by the user... so when they click the sort button then order matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good. Like @paulrehkugler says in his answer, you can just do `data = sortedArray` where you sort the array.

With the amount of data you have, consider *pre-sorting* your data in a  background thread. By my calculations, with 37,500 objects it would take 150K of memory if you keep around 3 arrays with different sort orders. So when the user chooses to sort by a particular column, you'd already have the data sorted, and you'd just swap the array that is used as the data source. For the user, sorting then would appear practically instantaneous.

Comment: Given my project I think this is the best solution to my issue. A big thanks to everyone who contributed.

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause of your UI hanging is that you're removing and adding all 37.5k objects between two arrays.

Try changing this:

```
[data removeAllObjects];  
[data addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];
```

to this:

```
data = sortedArray;
```

Comment: I actually had that at first. I get these objects from a different class that pulls it from a web database. The objects come in chunks and with every chunk I have to call `[data addObjectsFromArray:items];` where data is the array containing all the objects, and items is an array with new data to be appended to `data`. calling `data = sortedArray` changes `data` from a mutable array to a normal array, thus causing a crash because a normal array does not have a method called `addObjectsFromArray`

Comment: Because `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` returns a normal array, not a mutable array.

Answer (score 1):

For a large operation you should use a background queue, rather performing that on main queue and blocking UI. You could call reloadData on the main queue after data becomes available from the background operation:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            [self sortArray:<# your key #>];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
});
```

Also consider using Paul's suggestion, as from the previous answer.